# How to put this validation on asp.net file upload control?

Tags: asp.net

I have a fileUpload User Control FileUploadControl.ascx containing asp.net fileupload control and a requiredfield validator.

I have another usercontrol RenderingTemplate.ascx that contains two FileUploadControl.ascx.

RenderingTemplate.ascx is on page RenderingTemplateDetails.aspx, this page has save and cancel button.

Now My requirement is in case user selects a file in one fileupload control,he has to select in other as well. If he does not select any file,let postback happen.

I cannot use Requiredfieldvalidator as it fires for both. I tried adding onclientclick to page save button and check whether file upload has some text in it.but i didnot succedd.

Now i want this functionality to be a part of control so that i dont have to recode it on every page. IS there any clientside event on usercontrol which fires when save button of page is clicked. Please help and suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution will become easier if you add custom validator. Take a look at how to add client validation function to custom validator.

Add custom validator to both of the file uploads and then in client validation function, place a single javascript function,
Here is a simple example:

```
function ValidateUpload(source,args){
   //assume f1 and f2 are your file upload controls:
   var f1 = document.getElementById('f1'); //in case of asp.net control use clientID
   var f2 = document.getElementById('f2');
   if(f1.value == f2.value)
     args.IsValid = true;
   else
     args.IsValid = false;
}
```

Notes: you can use single custom validator as well, or you can use source and args.Value with some additional logic to solve this but I think this is the most simple implementation I find.